# XML file edit with Python script

Tags: python, xml

I need to write a Python script that reads and replaces some data in an XML file. 
The data that is replaced has to be read automatically from a directory (it's a file's name)

```
<setting name="abc" serializeAs="String">
<value>fw.version.1.1</value>
```

the `fw.version1.1` has to be replaced with the file name from a folder.

Could use some help:)

thanks,
Robert

Comment: OK, then write one. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the XML File looks something like that **test.xml:**

```
<someXml>
<setting name="abc" serializeAs="String"/>
<value>fw.version.1.1</value>
</someXml>
```

To read the XML Data from File:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xmlData = etree.parse('test.xml', parser )
```

Reading the text from the value Tag:

```
xmlData.xpath('//value')[0].text
```

Writing new text to the value Tag:

```
xmlData.xpath('//value')[0].text = "test"
```

And finally write your changes to the same (or any other) File:

```
xmlData.write( 'test.xml', pretty_print=True )
```